# How to dispaly Json Formatted DateTime into Angular Data

Tags: angularjs, json, datetime

**I have Datetime in my sqldb when im fetching data from database using Json formatted im Getting Datetime as a "/Date(820434600000)/"

Here im having some code which i copied from stackoverflow but not working please Guide me**

```
 app.filter("DateFilter", function () {
        var re = /\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//;
        return function (x) {
            var m = x.match(re);
            if (m) return new Date(parseInt(m[1]));
            else return null;
        };
    });
    <td>{{eee.DataofJoin | DateFilter | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</td>
```

Comment: what is the format of your Date string?

Comment: in my sqltable i have DateTime formate

Comment: i think angular date filter will do justice with it , no need to add additional filter

Comment: im getting error as "angular.js:13642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: jsDateFilterProvider <- jsDateFilter"

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting from database a instance of Date object, so if you bind the 
date to new Date got from DB as follows:

`$scope.date = new Date(820434600000);`

(will result in this "1995-12-31T18:30:00.000Z") and using angular filters for date you can display in any format you want;

In HTML you do this:

```
<p>{{date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</p>
```

This will result in displaying

`1995-12-31 20:30`

Angular takes care of that with built-in filters, no need for custom one. Though it's not best practice what you do, try using only the timestamp stored in DB.

Comment: Dinca Adrian  i want to apply its on my table not in a single column  already i written the code on Controller as mentioned above

Comment: Are you the one that stores the data into the DB? or are you just using it how it is now?